# BootStrap Android

Tags: android, css

Estou tentando fazer um projeto usando uns componentes do Bootstrap, mas está dando um
erro no XML do meu Layout. O erro:

> The following classes could not be instantiated

O artigo do desse projeto com Bootstrap peguei [nesse link](http://www.thiengo.com.br/img/post/file/vg1roq4bv2786bl3sb76vfg45576e166e5429ecf0414d173314cbfe92f.zip) e [nesse vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ07Y_iQ0dQ).

[image: Erro]

Comment: Por favor, não use imagens, cole o texto do erro e o XML relevante na própria questão. Imagens são ruins para leitura de erro geralmente (há exceções) e links externos podem vir a quebrar assim tornando difícil de ver o problema.

Comment: Bem vindo Ao SOpt, temos um certo critério para construir perguntas aqui, prefira sempre colocar o código ao invés da imagem, procure descrever bem o que está perguntando no titulo. descreva o erro, em qual contexto está aparecendo, o que exatamente você tentou, boa sorte

Comment: O link que você postou redireciona para o download de um arquivo `.zip`. Talvez seja melhor editar a pergunta e colocar o link do artigo/tutorial que leu, dificilmente alguém irá baixar o projeto para procurar por erros.

Comment: @renan, o link com o arquivo `.zip` não é um projeto, mas sim uma lib (eu acredito), que no caso, é a do `bootstrap`.